# Migrating Portable Class Library to new DNX Shared library?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, roslyn, dnx

I'm really confused by the new Dot Net Execution SDK and the new Shared Library form of cross-platform .net application/library.

I have some Portable Class Libraries, and I was planning to use these under the Mono environment (and possibly xamarin in the future). I picked PCL over a normal CL because it seemed logical for more compatibility.

With Visual Studio 2015 and DNX there seems to be more focus on cross platform support now. However, there seems like no way to target 4.6 in a PCL; Is it depreciated and we're supposed to move to the new .net core method?

So I'm wondering if I should or even can upgrade my PCL to DNX shared libraries, will these be compatible with Mono?

Do these DNX compiled libraries HAVE to run under the DNX environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCL support for .NET Framework 4.6 and .NET Core will be released soon, along with the Visual Studio Tools for Windows 10.  This release will add targets for UWP, .NET 4.6 and Asp.NET 5.0.

You should feel free to continue to use Portable Class Libraries to write single-binary libraries.

The DNX based class libraries are useful if you need to write platform specific code and produce a different binary for each framework you want to be able to target.

Comment: So the DNX / .Net Core stuff can then use my PCL?

Answer (score 1):

Portable Class Library support for ".NET Framework 4.6" and "ASP.NET Core 5.0" is included in Visual Studio 2015 RTM. You need to install the optional "Tools and Windows SDK 10.0.10240" hidden under "Universal Windows App Development Tools".

Comment: Installed that monster. No luck, cannot use Microsoft.Composition (portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81) from a dnx451 ASP.NET 5 (Beta 7) project. Says I must reference System.Reflection v4.0.0.0 to use a method accepting an `Assembly` as a parameter. Looks like the compiler cannot resolve the contract for the type under dnx451.